# Android Set textview text when creating static fragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have the following class

```
public static class TextPostFragment extends Fragment
{
    public static TextPostFragment newInstance()
    {
        TextPostFragment post = new TextPostFragment();
        post.setArguments(new Bundle());
        return post;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_text_post, container, false);

        return mainView;
    }
}
```

which is basically supposed to represent an individual post in a social media app. So basically I have a fragment that has several of these as its children.  I need to be able to edit the text of each post and set click listeners among other things, but I can't seem to be able to even get as far as editing the text. Basically if one of these fragments has a TextView named "name" how would I set the text for that? Should I not make this static? According to what I have read I should be making these static, but it is proving to be a royal pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `newInstance` to be:

```
public static TextPostFragment newInstance(String name)
```

then set the name to be a field in your arguments `Bundle`.  Then when this fragment is created you can extract the name from the arguments and set the text in the layout appropriately.  A static field or method is not what you want.